# Conspy: "Undefined reference" errors when trying to compile the latest version

Tags: compiling

[Conspy](https://sourceforge.net/projects/conspy/) is a neat remote control program for the TTY virtual consoles in Linux.

I am trying to **compile the latest** [v1.10-1](https://sourceforge.net/projects/conspy/files/) version, but after installing all the supposedly needed packages, I still have a **compilation error** that stops the procedure:

```
luis@utilite-desktop:~/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10$ make clean
test -z "conspy" || rm -f conspy
test -z "*~" || rm -f *~
rm -f *.o
luis@utilite-desktop:~/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10$ make
gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"conspy.c\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"conspy-c\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.10\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"conspy.c\ 1.10\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"conspy-c\" -DVERSION=\"1.10\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_FCNTL_H=1 -DHAVE_GETOPT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDARG_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_IOCTL_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TIME_H=1 -DHAVE_TERMIOS_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DTIME_WITH_SYS_TIME=1 -DRETSIGTYPE=void -DHAVE_SELECT=1 -DHAVE_STRTOL=1 -I.     -g -O2 -MT conspy.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/conspy.Tpo -c -o conspy.o conspy.c
conspy.c: In function 'process_command_line':
conspy.c:352:11: warning: ignoring return value of 'strtol', declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
mv -f .deps/conspy.Tpo .deps/conspy.Po
gcc  -g -O2   -o conspy conspy.o
conspy.o: In function `cleanup':
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:542: undefined reference to `endwin'
conspy.o: In function `conspy':
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:624: undefined reference to `wmove'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:625: undefined reference to `wclrtoeol'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:658: undefined reference to `wmove'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:659: undefined reference to `waddchnstr'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:660: undefined reference to `wchgat'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:680: undefined reference to `wmove'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:681: undefined reference to `waddchnstr'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:682: undefined reference to `wchgat'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:685: undefined reference to `wmove'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:686: undefined reference to `wrefresh'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:615: undefined reference to `LINES'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:615: undefined reference to `LINES'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:699: undefined reference to `endwin'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:700: undefined reference to `wrefresh'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:552: undefined reference to `LINES'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:552: undefined reference to `stdscr'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:552: undefined reference to `COLS'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:552: undefined reference to `curscr'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:729: undefined reference to `wrefresh'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:617: undefined reference to `stdscr'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:617: undefined reference to `stdscr'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:618: undefined reference to `stdscr'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:618: undefined reference to `stdscr'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:617: undefined reference to `wmove'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:618: undefined reference to `wclrtobot'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:779: undefined reference to `stdscr'
conspy.o: In function `setup':
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:499: undefined reference to `initscr'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:500: undefined reference to `nonl'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:515: undefined reference to `has_colors'
conspy.o: In function `main':
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:278: undefined reference to `tigetstr'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:280: undefined reference to `tigetstr'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:280: undefined reference to `putp'
conspy.o: In function `setup':
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:517: undefined reference to `start_color'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:529: undefined reference to `init_pair'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:519: undefined reference to `acs_map'
/home/luis/Temporal/conspy/conspy-1.10/conspy.c:519: undefined reference to `COLOR_PAIRS'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [conspy] Error 1
```

The compilation yields **similar errors** on:

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on PC (portable computer from ASUS).
- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on Utilite from Compulab (an embedded device like RaspBerry).

**Why** is the building failing with that `undefined reference` error and how could it be **solved**?

Comment: It looks like it is failing to link the `libncurses` library (`-lncurses`), perhaps because your system doesn't have the `libncurses5-dev` package installed: try installing it and then re-running the `./configure` script. BTW `conspy-1.8` seems to be available from the 14.04 repository.

Comment: @steeldriver , I don't know much about compiling. Could you please explain why/when should the `./configure` script be executed? When I miss some package, I just install it and try again to `make`.

Comment: @steeldriver: yes, I know that Ubuntu includes `conspy-1.8`. I was just trying to update it.

Comment: The order would be (1) install the missing package (2) run `./configure` in the conspy-1.10 directory, which should generate a new `Makefile` (3) run `make`

Comment: I think your answer was right, @steeldriver : `libncurses5-dev` was already installed, so I ran `./configure`, and then `make` did not fail anymore. You should write it down as an answer. If possible, explain how could you tell the problem was on `libncurses5-dev`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those arriving here, these are the **needed packages** for ConSpy:

```
# apt-get install libtool libncurses5-dev fakeroot sudo automake devscripts
```

The problem (or so I believe): as @SteelDriver pointed, between each `make` attempt I was not doing the needed `./configure`.

UPDATE 2015-10-16:

- There is no need to do `/configure` since v1.13 and later. In fact, there is no such script on the sources no more. It seems to be included on the compilation script.